# Is there a way to make an Int variable equal (==) to all the numbers stored in an Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, console, integer

Okay so I'm new to coding and I just started an account here to get some help.
My assignement is to code an application that will print numbers from 0-100 in the console. But not "32, 44 and 77".
I know I could make many If statement, but my question is if I can store the three numbers in an Array and then say like:

```
        int numZero = 0;
        int[] num = { 32, 44, 77 };
        
        while (numZero <= 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numZero);
            numZero++;

         // I know the num needs to have a value assigned. But can I make the "numZero" go through the three numbers in num?
           
            if (numZero == num [])  
            {
                numZero++;
            }
```

thankful for advice!

Comment: Unless you're explicitly instructed to use an array, I would use a _for loop_ and explicitly compare the loop variable to 32, 44, and 47.

Comment: using System.Linq; => num.Contains(numZero);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a for loop from 0 to 100 and in the loop you test if the index [`Exists()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.array.exists) in the array to not print else to print.

You can also use the Linq extension method [`Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains) instead of `Array.Exists()`.

Doing that you will have 3 lines of code:

- for
- if !contains
- print (you do nothing if contains).

Thus you can try this:

```
using System.Linq;

int[] num = { 32, 44, 77 };

for ( int index = 0; index <= 100; index++ )
  if ( !num.Contains(index) )
    Console.WriteLine(index);
```

You can aslo write:

```
foreach ( int index in Enumerable.Range(0, 101) )
  if ( !num.Contains(index) )
    Console.WriteLine(index);
```

Using [`Enumerable.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range) avoids manipulating index and increment, so the code is cleaner and more secure.

*Note*: if 100 is not included change `<=` to `<`, or use `Range(0, 100)`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me back in the days! I now look back at this with a smile.